# Chrome incognito not so incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I live in the U.S. and my browser language is English, my windows 10 is in English too, but how come when I open https://onedrive.live.com/ in incognito mode they still "know" I am Chinese and redirect me to https://onedrive.live.com/about/zh-cn/ ? I tried this on other browsers most of them open English page. So Chrome incognito still kind of "leaks" some of my infomation to the webserver?

Comment: Well,actually it is the ISP and not the chrome at fault, because when you open a website, a request is passed to the ISP and then to the servers. Since ISP needs to send information like location, it redirects you to the Chinese page.

Comment: Incognito mode isn’t about privacy necessarily it’s about not being able to identify you through your cookies.  Your ISP is leaking the data not Chrome.

Comment: What are the settings in your DNS resolution route? It's possible Microsoft is using IP-based redirection, but it seems more likely that you are using software settings that indicate a Chinese preference (like language or DNS).

Comment: @Valay_17 that is absolute nonsense. The ISP normally doesn't send anything extra, even less the location (which is exactly why GEOIP databases exist).

Answer (score 3):

What Chrome in incognito mode probably still sends additionally to the things mentioned by DrZoo is the language preference: You can view it under chrome://settings/?search=language (for a german Chrome installation you need to search for "sprache", so chinese chrome might be a different search term too).

In the first dropdown you can set which languages should be advertized to the server to provide you with the best fitting site translation. The order from top to bottom is the one advertized to the server in the "Accept-Language" HTTP header. In the submenu of any item you can additionally set in which language Chrome will be displayed.

As for other browsers with a similar situation:
Firefox has the setting under "intl.accept_languages" in the about:config page if you find the dialog menu options in the regular settings menu behind "Set preferred languages for displaying websites" too counter intuitive.

Edge/Internet Explorer should use the computers regional settings. I'm not sure about this though. A setting for this value inside the browser itself is missing. If you comb through the "Internet Options" you'll at one time end up in the computer preferred language settings.

Comment: +1 I also feel that this is the main reason, but it would have been nice to explain how to check it - hence my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Using incognito mode does not mask your IP address. It only pertains to not keeping certain data on the device you're browsing from.

The "new tab" incognito page specifically says:

*Chrome **won't save** the following information:*

- Your browsing history
- Cookies and site data
- Information entered into forms

*Your activity **might still be visible to***: (the word **might** here more-so means yes they can see)

- Websites you visit
- Your employer or school
- Your internet service provider

For you to mask your source IP information, you will need to use a VPN.

Comment: But I live in NYC. Even they got my IP, why should they show me a Chinese page? I use optimum a very common ISP in New York, if this is their fault, where did they get the notion that I am Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here goes:

1. It's possible you "contaminated" your incognito session. Keep in mind that as long as you have an incognito window or tab open somewhere, all other incognito windows share the same session.
   For example, if you opened incognito, visited some popular chinese site (which most probably loads a tonne of 3rd party tracking / ads stuff), minimized incognito and then visited another site in a new incognito window, it is possible the 2nd site finds out info from the first site (if it used tracking cookies or some 2rd party tracking etc).
2. it's possible you're using some extension or browser library that has also been enabled/allowed in incognito.

To be absolutely sure, I suggest the following:

1. close chrome completely
2. disable all extensions
3. open a new icognito window, but don't visit anything yet
4. open the developer tools (easiest way is: right click anywhere in the window and click "Inspect" menu item)
5. switch to the network tab in the dev tools
6. open https://onedrive.live.com/ in the same window
7. check the request and response of the *first successful item* shown in the network tab:
   [image: network screenshot]
   *(I've marked the interesting parts, just check yours and see what is being sent in the request)*